# Match the column values between two tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables:

ReservationName

```
   +-------+-------+-------+-------+  
   |            Name               |  
   +-------+-------+-------+-------+   
   | Brad Pitt                     |  
   | Morgan Freeman                |  
   | Bobby deniro                  |  
   +-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

BookingDetails

```
   +-------+-------+-------+-------+  
   | Name           | ID   | Eid   |  
   +-------+-------+-------+-------+   
   | Brad Pitt      | 1    | ab123 |  
   | Morgan Freeman | 2    | pq123 |  
   | Bobby deniro   | 3    | rs123 |  
   +-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I have to match the names in ReservationName with BookingDetails .

If they are same (count and value) .

Above example of mine should return true as names are identical and count is 3.
The aforementioned condition is part of  **If exists** logic that I am using in a stored procedure.

Comment: You can use joins to match the names. What do you need exactly?

Comment: @gaganshera : if exists(Names and count is matched ) then set a scalar val to 1

Comment: What and where is the count? Requirement still isn't clear.

Comment: @gaganshera : Apologies for not making things clear. The name  column has to be identical. Hope it clarifies.

Comment: Doing a join like `SELECT *, count(*) nameCount FROM ReservationName t1 JOIN BookingDetails t2 ON (t1.Name = t2.Name)` will return all the matched rows. I don't understand the exact requirement but I think thats what you want.

Answer (score 1):

One method to determine which names are not in both tables is to use `full outer join`:

```
select *
from ReservationName rn full outer join
     BookingDetails bd
     on rn.name = bd.name
where rn.name is null or bd.name is null;
```

You can use this in an `if` using `exists`:

```
if (exists (select 1
            from ReservationName rn full outer join
                 BookingDetails bd
                 on rn.name = bd.name
            where rn.name is null or bd.name is null
           )
    )
begin
    -- not matching code
end;
```

Note:  This version assumes (as in your question) that the names are unique in each table.  If this is not the case, then ask *another* question with more information on how to handle duplicate names.  Specifically address the question of what to do if the number of duplicates differs between the tables.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, go with below Query:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(Name)
FROM 
    (SELECT R.Name
    FROM ReservationName R 
    INNER JOIN BookingDetails B ON R.Name = B.Name) A
```

Please describe the problem in details if this is not the solution you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirements:-

- Check count is matched.
- Check name is matched.

Use the next `IF` code:-

```
IF (
        /*check count is matched*/
        (SELECT COUNT(Name) FROM ReservationName) = (SELECT COUNT(Name) FROM BookingDetails) 
        AND
        /*check name is matched*/
        (SELECT COUNT(Name) FROM ReservationName where Name  
            NOT IN (SELECT Name FROM BookingDetails)) = 0
    )
BEGIN
    SELECT 1 -- Name and count are matched
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT 0
END
```

Comment: Getting this error . Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'BRAD PITT' to data type int

Comment: @PiyushSing, The answer has been updated, waiting ur feedback.

Comment: Thanks @ahmed abdelqader : Between I have also suggested one answer couple of hours back and it too is working file.

Answer (score 0):

```
if 
(
not exists (
SELECT Name FROM ReservationName 
EXCEPT
SELECT Name FROM BookingDetails
           )
and
not exists ( SELECT Name FROM ReservationName
             except
              SELECT Name FROM BookingDetails 
           )
)
BEGIN
    SELECT 1 -- Name and count are matched
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  SELECT 0
END
```